# What is the plural of "brother", "brothers" or "brethren"?

Tags: plural-forms, grammatical-number, kinship-terms

In English books, I read  that the plural of *brother* was given as *brethren*, but I hear people in movies or serials using *brothers*.

Which one is correct?

Is it the difference due to difference in American and British English?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use *brothers* in both speech and writing.

*Brethren* is a very old plural which is no longer in use, except in very narrow contexts: in works of fiction which depict historical times, or try to create a similar 'atmosphere'; in religious (or quasi-religious) works which embrace the language of the King James Bible; and in works which allude to uses of this sort, either mockingly or affectionately.

Comment: Brethren is still used in certain modern religious scenarios. For example, some Churches might refer to the leaders of the church as the Brethren. Certainly you're right that this word is not in common spoken or written English though.

Comment: @Matt I think that's covered in my second 'context', but I've made a small edit to make that clearer. These organizations (which aren't only churches - consider the Brethren of the Rosy Cross, for instance) use the old plural because it has an archaic, religious ring. And I suggest that ring derives primarily from the prestige of the KJV.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Would _brethren_ (in the cases where it is used) be understood to be less sexist than _brother_ and _sister_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think that circles in which *brethren* is used worry much about sounding sexist.

Comment: As usual, I don't ask the right question. I was not referring to those circles, but to how that word is understood outside. Is _brethren_ used for people of both genders? If that is the case, does the word sound less sexist? I ask because I know people didn't like using _mankind_ much.

Comment: @kiamlaluno *Brethren* may be used in an inclusive sense by the people who use it, and that may be regarded as sexist by the people who don't. Those who use it belong for the most part to highly patriarchal subcultures where  those who are concerned about sexism will find much more pressing issues to chafe at than the language!

Comment: No, *brethren* is not generally usually used for people of both genders; the corresponding word is *sistren* (sometimes *sistern* in old documents). I suppose that some formerly all-male organizations which have now let women in might use *brethren* for both sexes.

Answer (score 10):

The plural of *brother* as in "male sibling" is always *brothers*.

> He had six brothers and three sisters, so family gatherings tended to be large affairs.

The origin of *brethren* is an old type of plural for *brother*, but it is no longer used in that sense. Nowadays, it is only ever used in the context of fraternal or religious organizations: you can be a *member of* the brethren, but you don't *have* brethren.

Bottom line: 99.999% of the time, the plural you should use is *brothers*.

Comment: Or: Don't use *brethren* unless somebody else uses it first.

Comment: @StoneyB I hope the other person is not waiting for me to use it first when I am waiting for him/her to use it first. `;)`

Answer (score 5):

*Brothers* is the correct term for referring to your male siblings.

In modern English, *brethren* is uncommon, and it no longer ever refers to your male siblings. It can be used in the following scenarios:

1. To refer to members of your religious group (esp. some [Protestant Christian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brethren) groups)

   > The Brethren are meeting on Sunday at 4 for Bible-study class at Julie's house.
2. Uncommonly it can also refer to some other pseudo-religious or old fashioned clubs and societies:

   > Meet Jeff. He is one of our Brethren from the [Masons'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry) in Bellingham here to visit for a week.
3. To refer to members of your extended family (uncommon British English, esp. referring to extended family *en-masse*):

   > We're going to my grandparent's house this Christmas. The entire Smith brethren are descending on Yorkshire, so we'll also be able to Christine and Jeff.

Comment: I might say, "I was stuck down in the mine for four days with my _brethren_," but, as Matt said, that would be highly unusual. I'd probably opt for "_with my fellow miners_" instead, unless, for some reason, I wanted to put some sort of religious connotation in my sentence. That sort of usage would be quite rare, though.

Comment: One additional use is for members of a panel of judges. The member of the US Supreme Court, in particular, are sometimes called "Brethren" and there is a book about the court with that title.

Answer (score 1):

In fraternal organizations founded back when archaic English was contemporary English (such as the Masons), "brethren" is used to make formal address to assembled brothers, or formal plural reference to brothers. In casual conversation, "brothers" seems to be usual.

There is a corresponding word for a sisterhood - "sistren" - which appears to be having a revival, if Google is any guide.

Comment: The word *sistren* may only be having a revival because it is displacing the (dialect) variant *sistern*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brethren+and+sistern%2Cbrethren+and+sistren+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrethren%20and%20sistern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrethren%20and%20sistren%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

Those who also know basic Spanish grammar might find it easier to think of word like thee, ye, thou, brethren, and such as being like the formal "Vosotros" form, which have mostly been displaced by the less formal "Tu" form, of you, brother, yes, and such.  When teaching English as a Second language, this made sense to the Hispanic kids when helping them with Shakespeare's English.

Answer (score 0):

Brethren is mostly used to refer community faith which share common faith/belief/character....it further shows the connectdness between the group that is refered. The Holly bible especially KJV refers Brethren showing the Onenes/interconnectdness

Comment: Mixed-gender Odd Fellows lodges use both **brethren** and **members** interchangeably to refer to all members collectively, regardless of gender identity.